# Adjust camera orientation through code (Unity3D)

Tags: c#, vector, unity-game-engine, camera

I posted this same question on the Unity Ask forums, but I'm not getting a response so I hope someone here will help.  I am working on a game where the camera needs to focus on a mountain at the center of an island. The camera works by rotating (using [Transform.RotateAround](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html)) around a point within that mountain. The camera also needs to pan right and left, which I do by [Translating it on its local left and right vectors](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html). However, once you use enough of Translate and RotateAround, the camera becomes tilted to the side, and it gets progressively worse as you play.

I have tried correcting it by running this function every frame:

```
private void StraightenCamera()
 {
     //tilt it upward so it is always oriented right
     //goal: make the local up vector lie in the plane defined by the local forward and global up vector
     //http://www.vitutor.com/geometry/distance/line_plane.html
     Vector3 localForward = this.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
     Vector3 globalUp = Vector3.up;
     Vector3 u = this.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.up);
     Vector3 n = Vector3.Cross(localForward, globalUp);
     float numerator = Mathf.Abs(n.x * u.x + n.y * u.y + n.z * u.z);
     float denominator = Mathf.Sqrt(n.x * n.x + n.y * n.y + n.z * n.z) + Mathf.Sqrt(u.x * u.x + u.y * u.y + u.z * u.z);
     float angle = Mathf.Rad2Deg * Mathf.Asin(numerator / denominator);
     this.transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, angle, Space.Self);
 }
```

This function mostly works, however there is a catch. It'll rotate the camera to the correct orientation after a few transformations, and then it'll decide to rotate the wrong way until it corrects to be perfectly upside down from where it should be. Mess around with it a little bit more and it'll correct itself to the right orientation, but as you continue to play it'll get confused and flip upside down again. I don't understand what is triggering the flipping, or where the problem in my math is. Does anyone see it?

Explanation of the above function: My thinking was that as it reorients itself, its local up vector was getting tilted. I don't care where it points, so long as it is in the plane defined by the local forward vector (wherever the player may have pointed that), and the global up vector. I am rotating the camera around its local forward axis in an attempt to maintain this condition. One hint that my math is off is that it doesn't correct this misalignment in a single frame like I intend, but it does so gradually, either when it is correcting to the correct orientation or upside down. The website I got the formula from is in a comment in the function, and linked below.

Video of the problem: https://youtu.be/J3a__u8vrYo

The source of the formula I am using: http://www.vitutor.com/geometry/distance/line_plane.html

Thank you for any help you may be able to provide!

Comment: I don't understand your code too well (probably my fault since I haven't done vector math in a while), but I think the problem lies in the arcsine operation. Arcsine flips once you reach 1 and -1.

Comment: It seems like the initial problem should be able to be solved, rather than doing a bunch of math to fix the camera every frame. Could you post a video of that problem?

Comment: There is video of the problem, in the YouTube link at the bottom of the post

Comment: why not use only local rotation for the camera and limit Roll rotation "Z"?

Comment: I'm trying to do that (unless I'm misunderstanding your comment), but I need the global up vector because that is not constant in local space.  I figured the angle would be the same regardless of if I did it in local space or world space, so I just picked one.

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative approach if you want to try it.

Have a GameObject as your camera's focal point. Make the gameObject a child of the camera. Call LookAt(theGameObject) when the camera moves. When panning, the gameObject will translate with the camera because of the parent-child relationship so the look at will still focus on the gameObject.

To rotate, you can RotateAround the target gameObject.

Comment: I think that'll have to be how I end up doing it.  Thanks for the suggestion.